# CORS request not applying correct Golang

Tags: go, backend

Using the package rs/cors in for Gin Gonic framework and can not figure out why corsConfig is not applying to my localhost frontend. I have tried various cors packages for golang and none of them seem to work for me. I want to be able to test locally for my backend and front end services without using the Google chrome extension. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    corsConfig := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"},
        AllowedMethods:     []string{"PUT", "PATCH", "GET", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"},
        AllowedHeaders: []string{"*"},
        AllowCredentials: false,
        MaxAge: int(12 * time.Hour),
    })
    
    router.Use(corsConfig)

    connDB, err := postgres.InitDB()     
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    defer connDB.Close()
    // Our server will live in the routes package
    routes.Run()
}
```

```
import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

var (
    router = gin.Default()
)

// Run will start the server
func Run() {

    getRoutes()
    router.Run(":8000")
}

// getRoutes will create our routes of our entire application
// this way every group of routes can be defined in their own file
// so this one won't be so messy
func getRoutes() {
    v1 := router.Group("/v1")
    addUserRoutes(v1)
    addPingRoutes(v1)

    v2 := router.Group("/v2")
    addPingRoutes(v2)

    router.GET("/testing", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, "hello")
    })
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a variable called `router` in `main` and configuring it with `corsConfig`:

```
router := gin.Default()
...
router.Use(corsConfig)
```

These are the only times that this variable is [referred to](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope).

You are then creating a separate variable; also called `router` in your `routes` package:

```
var (
    router = gin.Default()
)
```

The two variables are totally separate. The `corsConfig` is processed against one (in `main`) but it is the other one (from the `routes` module) that you are using to serve your interface.

There are a few ways to solve this:

- In `main()` get rid of `router := gin.Default()` and use `routes.router.Use(corsConfig)` (not [really recommend](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/06/11/go-without-package-scoped-variables)).
- Setup and add `corsConfig` in `getRoutes()`
- Pass the router into `Run()` and add the routes etc.

Comment: I have just tried all three of those methods and still no success. I have tried three different browsers also and getting the same problem. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` missing.

Comment: Then please post updated code with the `corsConfig` applied to the router and I'll take another look. Ideally post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (i.e. single file; no database stuff etc); I suspect that if you do this you will find your example works.

Comment: Okay so the corsConfig does work when I setup in the `getRoutes()` method. I noticed the code works for endpoints that are not grouped by the Router.

Comment: The handler will only be called when you are using an `*Engine` (what `gin.New()` returns) that it has been applied to (i.e. with `.Use()`). Note that I am guessing that you are using `github.com/rs/cors/wrapper/gin` because your question did not specify (there are quite a few CORS packages for gin).

Comment: Okay cool, I reverted back to not using Groups anyway I am a newbie at Golang and used that for a tutorial. I am curious how the code would look if I wanted to be able to use groups. And yes I am using `github.com/rs/cors/wrapper/gin`

Comment: Good luck. By the way a lot of development servers (e.g. Angular CLI, [react](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) etc) will proxy requests for your API (saving the need to muck around with CORS).

Comment: Im using react on the front end lol and working on setting up a NGINX server to handle this  in the future.